# Run Rails on Windows Box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, operating-system

Are there any benefits to running Rails on a Windows box? Does anybody prefer Windows as a platform for this sort of thing? I am almost a pure novice, but I can't see any reason not to use some nix distro.

Comment: when company policy disallows dual booting and enforces the use of windows, you may still be able to have rails installer.

Comment: This would be a production server.

Comment: the vast vast majority of rails is done on mac/linux/unix. If that's what you're comfortable with, stick with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that running Rails on Windows can be cumbersome. Installing/running/deploying on nix is the best way to get Rails up and running. In many distros Rails comes included so nothing to do except a few gem commands to update rails to the latest version and you're good to go.

Comment: I will take this as, "no there is no reason"